# SQL Subquery/Left Join Issue

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working on a project where a student takes a test - with a few of the qualifiers being that they can only take tests that they are registered for (by class) and that they can only take each test once. I have it figured out for the most part.. but I am working on a SELECT statement for use in a dropdown menu. And I'm having an issue.

Relevant structure, with only column names:

### User table

- UserID

### Quiz table

- QuizID

### Complete table

- UserID
- QuizID

So basically, after a quiz is completed - all the results go to another table called Results, but an entry is also made in the Complete table which records the user's ID and the quiz ID. Then I make the following SQL statement to populate the dropdown.

```
SELECT Quiz.QuizID, Quiz.QuizName
FROM Quiz
LEFT JOIN Complete ON Complete.QuizID = Quiz.QuizID
WHERE Complete.QuizID IS NULL
AND Quiz.Class = 'History'
```

Which works - technically. But you'll see what the issue here is.. if someone in the History class takes the test.. then no one else in the History class can take the test. So I have to separate that by the User ID. I've tried something like:

```
SELECT Quiz.QuizID, Quiz.QuizName
FROM Quiz
LEFT JOIN Complete ON Complete.QuizID = Quiz.QuizID
WHERE Complete.QuizID IS NULL
AND Quiz.Class = 'History'
AND Complete.UserID = (SELECT UserID
FROM User
WHERE UserID = '2')
```

Where '2' is a placeholder for the Session UserID - but also a tester because I have two history tests and I have an entry saying that this student has taken one of them. But I can't get this working properly.

Any help on what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Well, first of all, what is the result that you want?, you explained your problem, but only told us "I want to populate the dropdown". So, with what do you want to populate your dropdown?

Comment: Oh sorry - I want the dropdown to populate with the tests that the user has NOT taken. The answer below fixes that, it was just an issue of me having no down Joins in a while.

Answer (score 1):

Move the condition on `UserID` to the `on` clause:

```
SELECT Quiz.QuizID, Quiz.QuizName
FROM   Quiz
LEFT JOIN 
       Complete 
ON     Complete.QuizID = Quiz.QuizID
       AND Complete.UserID = '2'
WHERE  Complete.QuizID IS NULL
       and Quiz.Class = 'History'
```

Now, it will look only for `Complete` records for user `2`.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?  It moves your userId check to your `JOIN` criteria:

```
SELECT Quiz.QuizID, Quiz.QuizName
FROM Quiz
   LEFT JOIN Complete ON Complete.QuizID = Quiz.QuizID
      AND Complete.UserID = 2
WHERE Complete.QuizID IS NULL
   AND Quiz.Class = 'History'
```

By checking for the userId in your `WHERE` criteria, it negates the `LEFT JOIN`.  Complete.QuizId could never be `NULL` if Complete.UserId = 2.

Comment: Excellent, yes.. this is what I was looking for. Just a bit airheaded when it came down to it. Now to just reverse it so they can do the same thing with the tests they HAVE completed and I'll be mostly done.

Comment: @Mathematical -- np, glad we could help!  Just replace the LEFT JOIN with an INNER JOIN and remove the IS NULL check and you should have the other.  Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

The other solutions suggested should work, but in case you want to keep the where conditions separated by the join clause, I think a simple OR should do the trick:

```
   SELECT Quiz.QuizID, 
          Quiz.QuizName
     FROM Quiz
LEFT JOIN Complete 
       ON Complete.QuizID = Quiz.QuizID
    WHERE (Complete.QuizID IS NULL -- let's show the quiz never completed
          OR
           Complete.UserID <> 2    -- or completed by someone who isn't 2 :)
          )
      AND Quiz.Class = 'History'
```